# How can I show the remote validation message with a jquery in MVC3?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, remote-validation

I have a JQuery to show a remote validation message but I only want it to execute for the remote validation and not the required validation.

So far I have

```
$('#MyElement').keyup(function () {    
         if (!!myEmailTimeoutChecker) {    
            clearTimeout(myEmailTimeoutChecker);    
         }    
         myEmailTimeoutChecker = setTimeout(verifyMyElement, 2000)    
 });
```

So it validates if 2 seconds have gone by and in the `verifyMyElement` method, I call `$('#MyElement').valid();`  Maybe I just need to do something a little bit different, not really sure but again, I only want to see the remote validation message and not the required validation message.  The required validation message should only show on form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `valid()` method will validate all the validation rules that were put in place.  If you want one that is separate, a custom one should be made, not using the built in one.